# After taking photo, UIImagePickerController returning empty black photo

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

In my application I am using native UIImagePickerController class to take photo.
Not frequently, but sometimes user takes a photo using UIImagePickerController. After taping the circle take photo button, system respond 10 to 20 second later with a black empty photo. If user click the 'Use Photo' button, then application crashes.

[image]

This is not a frequent issue. But once or twice in a month our users are facing this weird crash issue. We started facing this crash issue from iOS 10.x.
Is there anyone faced similar type of issue? Opened a ticket in Bug report apple. But wanted to see if there is anyone else who faced similar type of crash issue.

Comment: Did you make any subclass of UIImagePickerController?

Comment: nope. I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known UIImagePickerController bug. I reported to Apple and below is the response from Apple -

Duplicate of 19953748

*Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of another issue and will be closed. 
The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title, state, product and rank.
If you have any questions or concerns, please update your report directly here: http://bugreport.apple.com/.*

So I guess, i have to wait until they release a new version with this fix.